# What is the difference in Scripting Language and Pattern Matching techniques?

Tags: scripting, pattern-matching, scripting-language

Could you please clarify between the scripting language and pattern matching technique.

Is there any association between the two.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a scripting language is interpreted rule by rule. A pattern matching technique tries to find a pattern in a set of data. It's like apples & oranges I'd say.